# Angular js , simple app not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, master-pages, paging

So , my website is working on paging , and its done by doing .load to div , i am not using angular JS to load child pages ,  I just want to use angular in my child pages.

This is my child page

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>


<div data-ng-app="myApp">

    <div data-ng-controller="appCtrl">
      <p>{{greeting.text}}, world </p>
    </div> 


</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var appname = angular.module('myApp', []);
        appname.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',
          function ($scope) {
              $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
          }]);
    })

</script>
```

Its loaded to masterPage/Index but angular JS is not working , it doesnt do anything , Am i doing it wrong ?

If i load page its self , without index , application is working ,but with index it doesnt

I am getting this console output message : UPDATE putting body instead of div  removed this console output , but still my app is not working. And yet again my whole paging sistem wont work if i have body in it , it removes it when loads page so jeah

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $controllerProvider from myApp
```

Comment: Check your development console. Any errors?

Comment: @JMK Sorry for late update , i have added it to main question

Comment: You are using a really old version of Angular, have you tried the most recent stable version (1.4.9)? Or do you need to use that version?

Comment: if you pull the angular code out of document.ready and add the script tag to html head section, it works fine for me. Also try updating your angular version too.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared an app name:

```
<div data-ng-app>
```

should be

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
```

And then in your code you can do:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Comment: Doesnt really matter ,it doesnt work anyway, i have changed my code , check main question , and still it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You were using jQuery to wait for the document ready event, but jQuery hasnt been included.

Also you don't need the data prefix on app and controller.

Try this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript"
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
      <p>{{greeting.text}}, world </p>
    </div> 


</div>

<script>

        var appname = angular.module('myApp', []);
        appname.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',
          function ($scope) {
              $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
          }]);


</script>
```

Comment: Tried , still doesnt work , i am adding data prefix just because visual studio thinks its an arror in html5 , it doesnt harm anything . I guess my index page is doing something wierd to child page so it doesnt run angular or something o0 i am really new to angular and dont understand why this wont work on child page , but child page it self works just fine